# Mapping the binned data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mapping, binning

```
df12.head()
            COMPONENT_ID   PSRO       binned   PSRO_SPEED
4080  11S02CY383YH1934794910  7.470  (7.4, 7.65]  (7.4, 7.65]
4722  11S02CY388YH1934786330  7.491  (7.4, 7.65]  (7.4, 7.65]
4708  11S02CY388YH1934782718  7.497  (7.4, 7.65]  (7.4, 7.65]
4726  11S02CY388YH1934786336  7.564  (7.4, 7.65]  (7.4, 7.65]
4707  11S02CY388YH1934782709  7.581  (7.4, 7.65]  (7.4, 7.65]
```

I want that binned data to map to different values. 
I tried

```
df12['PSRO_SPEED']=df12['PSRO_SPEED'].map({'(7.4,7.65]': 'high_speed'})
```

But this is not working. It is changing df12['PSRO_SPEED'] to NAN.

Comment: What do you get when you do `print(df12.PSRO_SPEED.dtype)`

Comment: It gives me as Category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is [`Interval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html), not string, so possible solution is:

```
i = pd.Interval(7.4,7.65, closed='right')
df12['PSRO_SPEED']=df12['PSRO_SPEED'].map({i: 'high_speed'})
```

Or for your solution is necessary convert column to strings:

```
df12['PSRO_SPEED']=df12['PSRO_SPEED'].astype(str).map({'(7.4,7.65]': 'high_speed'})
```

---

But better should be add parameter `label` to [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = [7.4,7.65,7.9,8.15,8.4,8.65] 
labels = ['lowest','low','medium','great','greatest']
df12['binned'] = pd.cut(df12['PSRO'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Comment: For me the second part of solution was convenient but it is not working ,I am getting NAN values

Comment: @Chinti - How are created `PSRO_SPEED` column? What is code?

Comment: I did df12['PSRO_SPEED']=df12['binned']...And then I wanted that to map with different string values. Be fore mapping 'binned ' and 'PSRO_speed' is category type

Comment: @Chinti - OK, so how is generate `binned` column? There is use `pd.cut` ?

Comment: bins = [7.4,7.65,7.9,8.15,8.4,8.65]   ……...                                           
df12['binned'] = pd.cut(df12['PSRO'], bins)                                                                             This was exact code